# how to split and handle the array data in Scala in more functional way

Tags: scala, functional-programming

My logic is simple. I have the following text lines and convert them to a Map:

```
a-1.0
b-text
c-
d-
e-2.0
```

Please note that value could be `null`. Here is my way in Scala to do that:

```
  var valueMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]()

  Source.fromFile("file/text").getLines().foreach(l=>{
    var temp = l.split("-")
    if(temp.size.equals(2)){
      valueMap += (temp(0)->temp(1))
    }else{
      valueMap += (temp(0)->"")
    }
  })
```

It works but it's more like `Java` way istead of `Scala` way.

Anyone could help me with implementation in more functional or more `Scala` way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `foreach` for this. `foreach` is evil. Use `map` instead.

Second, don't use `var`s. `val`s are OK in most cases.

Third, don't use mutable structures if you can.

Consideing this, here is what it can be converted to:

```
val valueMap = Source.fromFile("file/text").getLines().map(line => {
  line.split("-") match {
    case Array(k, v) => (k, v)
    case Array(k) => (k, "")
  }
}).toMap
```

Comment: I'm newbie to `Scala`. Why `foreach` is evil?I think `foreach` is just  give me a intuition that it's iterating.

Comment: In this case `map` does the heavy work for you. `map` is similar to `foreach` - it iterates through a collection and applies the given function to each element. The difference is that `foreach` does not yield any significant result (i.e. returns `Unit`) and `map` returns you a new collection transofrmed by the function you passed. `List(1, 2, 3).map(_ + 1)` returns you a new List with all elements incremented by 1 - `List(2, 3, 4)`